# How can I pass an object from container to class in Meteor and React?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to get a value in an object of javascript but it fails somehow. I managed to get an intended data from mongoDB by findOne method. Here is my code and console log.

```
const title = Questions.findOne({_id: props.match.params.id});
console.log(title);
```

Then console says:

Object {_id: "bpMgRnZxh5L4rQjP9", text: "Do you like apple?"}

What I wanna get is only the text in the object. I have already tried these.

```
console.log(title.text);
console.log(title[text]);
console.log(title["text"]);
console.log(title[0].text);
```

But I couldn't access to it... The error message is below.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined**

It sounds super easy but I couldn't solve by my self. Could anyone help me out?

**Additional Context**
I'm using Meteor and React. I would like to pass the text inside of the object from the container to the class. I would like to render the text in render(). But it doesn't receive any data from the container... The console.log in the container works well and shows the object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Questions } from '../../api/questions.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Answers } from '../../api/answers.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';

class MapClass extends React.Component{
  handleAlternate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const country = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();

    Answers.insert({
      country,
      yes: false,
      question_id:this.props.match._id,
      createdAt: new Date(), // current time
    });
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = '';
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const country = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();

    Answers.insert({
      country,
      yes: true,
      question_id: this.props.match.params.id,
      createdAt: new Date(), // current time
    });
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = '';
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: {
        title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
      },
      data: [
        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
        ['South America', 12],
        ['Canada', 5.5],
        ['France', 14],
        ['Russia', 5],
        ['Australia', 3.5],
      ],
    };
    this.state.data.push(['China', 40]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h1>{this.props.title.text}</h1>

        <Chart
          chartType="GeoChart"
          data={this.state.data}
          options={this.state.options}
          graph_id="ScatterChart"
          width="900px"
          height="400px"
          legend_toggle
        />
        <form className="new-task" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
          <input
            type="text"
            ref="textInput"
            placeholder="Type to add new tasks"
          />
          <button type="submit">Yes</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleAlternate.bind(this)}>No</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MapContainer = createContainer(props => {
  console.log(Questions.findOne({_id: props.match.params.id}));
  return {
    title: Questions.findOne({_id: props.match.params.id})
  };
}, MapClass);
```

Comment: `findOne` is asynchronous. See the examples in the documentation on how to do this properly.

Comment: @str Not in the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) shell it is not, and all methods are **synchronous** there. The value of `_id` suggests that meteor is in use. So it would be nice if the asker could actually confirm that and give context to where they are actually running the statement.

Comment: @NeilLunn But the example code has not been executed in the mongo shell.

Comment: @str How do **you** know that? Look carefully. First code block in the question and then the "output" is being shown. This suggests the method called is synchronous and is either A.) From the shell B.) From the browser console in a meteor app. The `_id` value as mentioned is consistent with how meteor defines them. I'm making observations on available information. You are making statements based on suppositions.

Comment: @NeilLunn There might be extensions to the shell that I do not know. But 1) the default way of querying data in the shell is `db.dbName.findOne`, 2) `console` is not defined in the shell, and 3) logging results from `findOne` queries in the shell are not prefixed by `Object`. So I assume the shown code is an oversimplification of the actual code that runs in a node.js environment.

Comment: @str Then browser and a Meteor app. And yes that means it's a synchronous call as a `minimongo` method. I'm asking the OP to clarify. How about waiting for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I should have put whole source code. Sorry for confusing. I added more information about the issue. I still  don't fully understand how to use container in meteor. Is it caused because the asynchronous method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that at the moment when the container is mounted, the data is not yet available. Since I do not see any subscriptions in your container I assume that you handle that elsewhere and thus there is no way of knowing when the data is ready. You have 2 options.

1) move the subscription into the container and use the subscription handle `ready()` function to assess if the data is ready. Show a spinner or something while it is not. Read [this](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#data).

2) use lodash/get function ([docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get)) to handle empty props. You would need to

`npm install --save lodash`

and then

`import get from 'lodash/get';`

and then in your class render method:

```
render() {
  const text = get(this.props, 'title.text', 'you-can-even-define-a-default-value-here');
  // then use `text` in your h1.
  return (...);
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'm trying to solve with using ready function and added a loading screen.